# File edit update doesn't apply (Sublime Text 3 and Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext3, fileupdate

At first, my file contained ***"@extends('layouts.app')"*** in my register.blade.php file. Later on, I edited it and put ***"@extends('layouts.nav')"***.

Now, my file structure is correct, everything is correct, but still when I open my project in browser, it says *"View [layouts.app] not found. (View: C:...\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)"*.

**Note: "In my register.blade.php file is written *"layouts.nav"*, not *"layouts.app"*!! 
It's not the first time that's happening, not only on this file. I'd fix it by changing the name, but I have no idea what's the root problem. Now because of resource routes, I can't change it. So please if anyone knows, help would be appreciated**

Comment: Did you take a look at [Laravel Recipes: Clearing the Application Cache](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/104/clearing-the-application-cache)?

Comment: Try running `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Yeah, you need to clear the views like the @JeuneGuerrier has said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your view cache by running the command `php artisan view:clear`